# Switching from amsrefs to biblatex

Tags: biblatex, amsrefs

I always used `amsrefs` as my references package. However, it seems like `biblatex` is better supported, and more widely used (at least in this community).  Compare 37 posts with the [amsrefs](/questions/tagged/amsrefs) tag to 3.6k posts with the [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) tag. The trigger for me to switch was the so-called *Oxford comma*, which seems to be [easy enough to remove](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168591/changing-and-to-and-removing-oxford-comma-in-bibliography?lq=1) using `biblatex`, and I have no idea how to do it with `amsrefs`.

However, I like some of the features of `amsrefs`, and I was wondering whether they can be emulated using `biblatex`. Examples:

- `msc-links` allow one adding links to MathSciNet using the `MRNUMBER` entry in the bib entry.
- With the [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301179/bold-book-names-in-amsrefs) of @egreg, I can make book names appear in bold with `amsrefs`.

Can I somehow emulate these, and more, with `biblatex`? Can I let `biblatex` adopt `amsrefs`'s defaults?

Do you agree it's a reasonable decision to switch?

Comment: Look at it this way: `amsrefs` had a big potential, in my opinion, but it's not developed nor maintained; `biblatex` has several styles and is actively developed.

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Yes. (Anything is possible with @egreg's help, but in Biblatex you might not even need it.) (3) Yes. (4) I don't think so. Not if you mean 'can I pass an option to the package like `amsstyle` and get the defaults?' But if you mean 'can I configure it to use those defaults?' then probably.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible to link to MathSciNet. This can be done as in [Biblatex and Pubmed/Pubmed Central IDs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864). Either as a manifestation of the `eprint` feature via

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:mrnumber}{%
  MR\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

and then

```
eprint     = {1678525},
eprinttype = {mrnumber},
```

in the `.bib` file.

Or as a separate field with a new datamodel. Call it `mrnumber.dbx`

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{mrnumber}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mrnumber}
```

then load that datamodel with the option `datamodel=mrnumber`, specify the formatting

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{mrnumber}{%
  MR\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

and print it

```
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{mrnumber}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}
```

You can see this in action in the example at the end.

---

It is very easily possible to make book titles bold

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

---

I don't know of an option to make the output look like `amsrefs` with only a few strokes on your keyboard. But I believe that many changes needed to the standard `biblatex` styles can be facilitated easily. Of course there might be the odd detail that is harder to implement.

---

If you need features that are only present in `biblatex` or significantly harder to get to work in `amsrefs`, a switch seems reasonable. But if you don't miss anything or can work around the deficiencies reasonably easy, you don't need to go through the ordeals of switching.

See also [When should I use amsrefs instead of regular bibtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628/35864) and [How popular is amsrefs in comparison with Bibtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247007/35864)

---

Example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mrnumber.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{mrnumber}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mrnumber}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, datamodel=mrnumber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{grabiner,
  author    = {David J. Grabiner},
  title     = {Brownian motion in a Weyl chamber, non-colliding particles, and random matrices},
  journal   = {Annales de l'Institut Henri Poincare (B) Probability and Statistics},
  volume    = {35},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {177-204},
  year      = {1999},
  doi       = {10.1016/S0246-0203(99)80010-7},
  mrnumber  = {1678525},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{mrnumber}{%
  MR\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{mrnumber}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{cicero,grabiner,sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: David J. Grabiner. ‘Brownian motion in a Weyl chamber, non-colliding particles, and random matrices’. In: Annales de l’Institut Henri Poincare (B) Probability and Statistics 35.2 (1999), pp. 177–204. doi: 10.1016/S0246-0203(99)80010-7. MR: 1678525.]